# From Java 1.4 to Java 6: any automated tool to update legacy code?

Tags: java

Our system will go through a platform upgrade that includes the replacement of Java 1.4  with Java 6.

Ideally, we would like to use an automated tool to introduce generics and enumerations to the code wherever possible and then, obviously, we would review the changes. Is there any tool that you would recommend for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA offers you special tool for generifying legacy collections.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I guess that would be the closest to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

> an automated tool to introduce
>   generics and enumerations to the code
>   wherever possible

This kind of tool is known as a "programmer". When it's available in fully automated form, you'll be out of a job (and probably spend your days as an amusing distraction to your new robotic overlords).

Seriously, this is way, *way* beyond what can be done automatically, especially the introduction of enumerations. The Generic type parameter for collections can perhaps be derived from context, but only for simple cases.

Comment: Wish I could upvote twice. Auto-generated code in these case is AWFUL.

Comment: It's difficult to disagree about enums. But part about generics and comment about auto-generated code make me think that you guys use Eclipse only.

Comment: I use Eclipse, but I used IntelliJ too, and frankly, this kind of migration should not be made automatically. It's a good occasion of refactoring and redesigning an application, those are not only languages features, it's paradigm changes.

Comment: If there is no something like *list.add ("string"); list.add (25.0); list.add (new Shape (1,1,2,2));* then IntelliJ will do the job.

Comment: Anyway it can help in most part of cases. Other should be changed manually. But it'll be much faster than do the whole stuff manually.

Comment: @Michael, this task would take centuries to our programmers to complete because the codebase is huge (hundreds if not thousands of Java classes). If we do this manually, maybe it will be the case of setting a culture in the team that if you touch a class or a method,  introduce generics, enumerations, etc. to it if possible.

Comment: @Bruno: You really should think of it in terms of cost vs. benefit: your code worked without Generics and Enumerations, and it won't stop working if you fail to introduce all the nice new features. They just make the code somewhat more maintainable. Thus, it doesn't make much sense to put much effort on introducing them in code that is stable, tested and unlikely to need much maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Michael is correct in that this cannot be done automatically.  Given this you could consider a phased approach whereby you start by generifying your APIs / interfaces (e.g. between subsystems) by casting collections at this point to the correct type.  You could also add assertions to verify that these casts were valid, which you could then later removed after testing.

Obviously the casting isn't ideal but it means you can update the API early on (assuming this is an API-based system) and then "correct" the internals later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced it is necessarily a good idea to "generifying" an old codebase:

- It won't improve performance, because the same class casts happen (behind the scenes) when you use generics as when you use raw types with explicit type casts.
- It is unlikely to fix bugs.  Significant bugs caused by casting to the wrong type have probably been found and fixed already.

So the only thing it would do is to make the code a bit more readable.  And on the downside you have the effort of making the changes and testing, and the risk that you may introduce new bugs.